# Python logging & 3rd party modules

Tags: python, logging

I'm struggling to get Python to log the way I want.  I've added some context to my log statements by adding a filter and updating the format string to print what's in the filter.  That works as expected as long as *all* the code is mine.

But if a 3rd party module logs something, it throws an error because that module doesn't know about my filter.

How do I get context into my logs without blowing up 3rd party module logging?

This code works fine in my modules.  But if a 3rd party module wants to log something, they don't know about my ContextFilter, which details the *nstid* I want in my log messages.

```py
import logging
import sys

import boto3
from ContextFilter import ContextFilter

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s nstid:%(nstid)8s %(message)s',
    handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)],
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addFilter(ContextFilter())

log.info("important information")
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: You configured *your* logger, not *theirs*. You'll need to check the documentation, or in the worst case the code, to see what loggers the other module uses.

Comment: Or, you need to configure the root logger (`logging.getLogger()`).

Comment: @chepner, add my filter to the root logger?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I needed using a CustomAdapter instead of a ContextFilter, but I'm still interested in other solutions:

CustomAdapter.py:

```py
import logging
import os

class CustomAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        nstid = os.environ['NSTID'] if 'NSTID' in os.environ else None
        return '[NSTID: %s] %s' % (nstid, msg), kwargs
```

```py
import logging
import os
import sys

import boto3
from CustomAdapter import CustomAdapter

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)],
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
)
log = CustomAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__), {})

log.info("important information")

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', region_name=os.environ['AWS_REGION'])
```

outputs:

```sh
2020-04-13 13:24:38 INFO     [NSTID: 24533] important information
2020-04-13 13:24:38 INFO     Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
```

the first line is from my code, the second from boto3

Comment: Your second line still does not has the NSTID